# How do I add a new Fieldcode in MS Word when running VBA From Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I'll be generating a document from access and want the field code "ListNum" to be used in the document. I have the following macro which when ran from MS word correctly adds the fieldcode in to the document.

```
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
    "LISTNUM  LegalDefault ", PreserveFormatting:=False
```

However when I run this from VBA in access through a word object it doesn't appear to work. The code in access is as follows.

```
Dim objApp As Object
Set objApp = GetObject("Word.Application")

    Set objApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objApp.Visible = True
    Set Word = objApp

    With Word
        .Documents.Add
        .activedocument.Fields.Add Range:=.Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="LISTNUM  LegalDefault ", PreserveFormatting:=False
    End With
```

If i use the "run" function

```
Word.Run "ListNum"
```

From access to call the macro in word it works too, while I can use this, it's not ideal as it relies on the user having this macro in their template

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the fix appears to be the following

```
Type:=wdFieldEmpty
```

Does not get recognised in access when moving over to word it seems, using the constant value of this is the correc thing to do, the following line works instead

```
.activedocument.Fields.Add Range:=MyRange, Type:=-1, Text:="LISTNUM  LegalDefault "
```

I found the constant number by using the object explorer in word.

Comment: If you use late binding (i.e. you have no reference set to the Word object model), this applies to all Word constants. -- Be sure to have [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of each module.  
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time, so it doesn't bite you at runtime. 
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor.

Comment: Yeah i ran into a similar problem a while ago and forgot about this. I had an error handler I hadn't properly defined for this module just yet and it wasn't coming up with the error messages just skipping past it (as i had told it to do at the time) sleep moment from me but all sorted now! Thanks.